# Distinct Arrangements of Balls on Tiles

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

> You want to put several balls on $8 \times 8$ tiles, such that all $16$ ball arrangements on its rows and columns are different. What is the minimum number of balls to be put?

Two arrangements of balls are different if there exists a ball on some $i$-th tile of the first one but no ball on $i$-th tile of the second one. (For row, the $i$-th tile means the $i$-th column; for column, the $i$-th tile means the $i$-th row.)

For example, we need at least $4$ balls for $3 \times 3$ tiles and the configuration as the following:

[image]

> **Bonus**: How about $N \times N$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off... who puts balls on tiles?  They roll away and not to mention the cat keeps batting at them.  Am I the only one who thinks about these things???

Sorry.  I like this problem, I know you didn't really ask, and this is now the distant future, but I'd like to solve the bigger question of **N x N** grids:

> An **N x N** grid requires **(3N-2)/2** balls to ensure the required **2N** unique combinations.  I will note an odd value for **N** requires that the equation be rounded up, and that **N=1** and **N=2** are not solvable for any # of balls.  This equation represents the limit using the least ball-centric combinations, but also represents the actual solution for all **N>2** because there is an easy-ish method for building the puzzle.

The big strategy I am putting forward is that you must first tackle the 1-ball combinations and everything else will fall into place.

> [image: ![8x8_1]

This is an example 8x8 grid.  I have labeled some of the rows and columns to remind myself how many balls I intend on putting in that row or column.  I have eight total 1-ball combinations and I must use all of them.  These four balls generate the eight combinations I need.

> [image: ![8x8_2]

But when I go to fill in the 2-ball combinations I have a problem.  The rows and columns, when added up, come out to different values.  This isn't a big deal, we just need to fix it up a bit in those last two rows.  I just sort of flipped the labels in the corner.

> [image: ![8x8_3]

The last step isn't magic, I just started filling in balls to satisfy the 2-ball rows and columns and it just sort of solved itself.  We have many 2-ball combinations at our disposal and better yet this alternating spacing happens to be awesome for not making duplicate combinations.  I don't know... maybe it is magic.

> [image: ![enter image description here]

So check this out.  This pattern emerges from filling in those 2-ball combinations.  N is odd here so you will note the labels in the lower corner look a bit different.  Bottom two rows look a little funny, and that's always going to happen.  I figure there's twelve or so different ways that pattern could end in the corner.

> [image: ![enter image description here]

I would love to know if there is a way to arrange things where you don't have to fix up the bit in the corner.  It's pretty elegant if not for that.  I had fun.

Comment: Woah finally.. A very great answer! And shouldn't it be $(3N-2)/2$ balls instead of $(3N+2)/2$? :) As the lowerbound is proven by @KradCigol , hence your construction is indeed optimal. Congratulations!! :D

Comment: Whoops, copy error.  I fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 8):

A solution in:

> 17
>
> ```
>  00000000
>  X0000000
>  0X00000X
>  00XX0000
>  000XXX00
>  0000XXXX
>  X0000XXX
>  0000000X
> ```

Borrowing from @Jaap:

> 11
>
> ```
>    ....x...
>    .....x..
>    ......x.
>    .......x
>    .x.....x
>    .xx.....
>    ..xx....
>    ...x....
> ```

Comment: Beat me to it. And a better solution is clearly not possible.

Answer (score 7):

I think this might be an optimal solution, but I’m not sure. (Edit: It's not optimal - one fewer balls is possible)

> ```
>    ....x...
>    .....x..
>    ......x.
>    .......x
>    xx......
>    .xx.....
>    ..xx....
>    x..x....
> ```

This generalises in an obvious way for even $N$ to give a solution with $3N/2$ balls. For odd $N$ you can do almost the same, but with one fewer row an column with two balls, giving a total of $(3N-1)/2$ balls.

Comment: nicely done! Your answer inspired me to solve mine. You were *so* *close*! The general formula was only slightly off. Thanks @Jaap

Answer (score 7):

Piggybacking off @JonMarkPerry:

> The answer is 11.

Proof:

> We have a total of 2N rows and columns, with each having a unique permutation of balls.
> We get N c 1 ways to place 1 ball.
>  We get N c 2 ways with 2,
>  And so on.
>  Now, we need to find the minimal number of balls to give each row a unique permutation.
> Note that N c 1 = N.
> N c 2 = N(N-1)
>  And so on.

Adding the two, we get

> N$^2$
> Which is clearly greater than 2N, assuming that $N>2$

So the requirement is:

> 0 balls for 1 row/column.
>  $N*1$ balls for next N row/columns.
> Remaining N require $2(2N-N-1)=2N-2$
> This adds up to a total minimum of
> $3N-2$
> We need to divide by two, as we counted each ball twice, once in a row and once in a column.

Therefore,

> The general formula is
> $ceil((3N-2)/2)$

Comment: what if N is odd?

Comment: We round it down, @JonMarkPerry.

Comment: By the way, I think I missed the one row without balls. And a few other errors. Will fix it later. It adds a good amount of error to the equation. Sorry, @JonMarkPerry!

Comment: how does your general formula give the answer as 11 for N=8?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Fixed that formula, thanks!

Comment: this answer provides the lower bound, however how to construct the arrangements for such lower bound? :)